# Случайный выбор между двумя числами

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Всем доброго дня!
Имеется массив чисел (все значения в нем могут быть **только** от 1 до 3)

```
new int[]{3,3,2,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,1}, вот например такой
```

Нужно поменять значение ячейки массива [i] таким образом, чтобы каждое [i] изменилось на другое, **допустимое** значение.
Например, если первое значение i=3, то его надо изменить на 1 или 2. И так далее.

Подскажите как это сделать?
То есть по сути мне нужно случайно выбрать одно значение из двух возможных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) можно что-то такое соорудить)

```
fun randomAllowedValue(excludedValue: Int): Int = mutableListOf(1,2,3).apply { remove(excludedValue) }.let { it[Random.nextInt(it.size)] }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

```
1 + (i+random(2))%3
```

где `random(2)` даёт 0 или 1 (не знаю, как это в джаве пишется)

Comment: Спасибо большое